# How can i update the status of the blockchian?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

How can I update the status of the blockchian?

1. I issue a transaction and pass an id to the smart contract. Smart contract A retrieves data from smart contract B and uses it to check whether a condition in the smart contract is true or not. If checked, save '*id, true*' otherwise '*id, false*.' My first question is: should there be a transaction to save this information on the blockchain? I only have the initial transaction sending id, so how is this possible?
2. I store *id, true*. After some time the value true becomes false. But if the old pair was stored on the blockchian and the blockchian is immutable, how can the copy be updated?

I am using Ethereum

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to store similar data in two places. Isn't it easier for contract A to query contract B when needed instead of storing stale data?

Comment: @Ismael actually I have a doubt. When is the first transaction mined? I want the data to be saved only after calling contract B. Only in that case I can check the condition and save 'id, true' or 'id, false'

Comment: If transactions are by the same account they are executed in order by the nonce field. If they are from different accounts then is up to the miner. You can force an order by waiting enough blocks after it was mined and before sending a new transaction.